# String split in java using advanced regex

Tags: java, regex, split

I'm trying to use String split in java, to split a whole document in substrings between
the tabs spaces and newlines but I want to exclude the cases where words exist between quotes.

Example:

this file

```
CATEGORYTYPE1
{
    CATEGORYSUBTYPE1
    {
        OPTION1 “ABcd efg1234”
        OPTION2 ABCdefg12345
        OPTION3 15
    }
    CATEGORYSUBTYPE2
    {
        OPTION1 “Blah Blah 123”
        OPTION2 Blah
        OPTION3 10
        OPTION4 "Blah"
    }
}
```

splits to these substrings(like shown in Eclipse debugger):

```
[CATEGORYTYPE1, {, CATEGORYTYPE1, {, OPTION1, “ABcd, efg1234”, OPTION2....
```

when I use my current regular expression which is this:

```
    String regex = "([\\n\\r\\s\\t]+)";

    String[] tokens = data.split(regex);
```

but what I want to achieve is to split it like this:

```
[CATEGORYTYPE1, {, CATEGORYTYPE1, {, OPTION1, “ABcd efg1234”, OPTION2....
```

(to not split the contents between quotes)

Is this possible to do with regular expressions and how?

Comment: You're better off using a full fledged parser for that. I'd recommend parboiled.

Comment: I'm trying to write my own :P

Comment: `[\n\r\s\t]+` is the same as `\s+`, since `\s` includes all of `\n`, `\r`, `\t`, `\f`, space, vertical tab.

Comment: When you say "quotes" do you mean "normal" double-quotes (`"`) or also `'`, `“` etc ? And what about escaped quotes, e.g how would you to split this: `abc "de\" fg" hi` ?

Comment: i was talking only about double-quotes, but an answer to all the above
would be great

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way of doing this:

```
str = "CATEGORYTYPE1\n" + 
"{\n" + 
"    CATEGORYSUBTYPE1\n" + 
"    {\n" + 
"        OPTION1 \"ABcd efg1234\"\n" + 
"        OPTION2 ABCdefg12345\n" + 
"        OPTION3 15\n" + 
"    }\n" + 
"    CATEGORYSUBTYPE2\n" + 
"    {\n" + 
"        OPTION1 \"Blah Blah 123\"\n" + 
"        OPTION2 Blah\n" + 
"        OPTION3 10\n" + 
"        OPTION4 \"Blah\"\n" + 
"    }\n" + 
"}\n";

String[] arr = str.split("(?s)(?=(([^\"]+\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\\s+");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

// OUTPUT
[CATEGORYTYPE1, {, CATEGORYSUBTYPE1, {, OPTION1, "ABcd efg1234", OPTION2, ABCdefg12345, ...
```

**Explanation:** It means match space or new line (`\s`) followed by EVEN number of double quotes (`"`). Hence `\s` between 2 double quotes characters will NOT be used in split and outside ones will be matched (since those are followed by even number of double quotes characters).

Comment: This answer is absolutely the best! I only now need to spend the 
next hour to decode that kung-fu ninja regex!:P Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

It seems complexe or even inadequate to use a split here, using a find is much easier, try this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] argv) {

        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();

        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+");
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(yourstring);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            result.add(m.group(0));
        }
    }
}
```

if you need to add other types of quotes (for example: `“xxxxx xxxxx”`) you can easily add them to the pattern:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("“[^”]+”|\"[^\"]+\"|\\S+");
```

you can allow escaped double quotes (`"xxx \"xxx\""`) with this:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\"(?:[^\"]+|(?<!\\)\")+\"|\\S+");
```

Comment: The code `Pattern.compile("\"(\\\\\"|[^\"])*\"|[^\\s\"]+")` will also take care of special cases like `OPTION1"A String"` and `"Another\" String"`.

Answer (score 0):

I know I joined the party rather late, but if you are looking for a fancy regex to "understand" escaped `"` as well, this one should work for you:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\S*?\".*?(?<!\\\\)\")+\\S*|\\S+");
Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
while (m.find()) { ... }
```

It will also parse something like this:
`ab "cd \"ef\" gh" ij "kl \"no pq\"\" rs"`
to:
`ab`, `"cd \"ef\" gh"`, `ij`, `"kl \"no pq\"\" rs"` (not getting confused by the odd number of escaped quotes (`\"`).

(Probably irrelevant, but this one will also "understand" `"` in the middle of a string, so it will parse this: `ab c" "d ef` to: `ab`, `c" "d`, `ef` - not that such a pattern is likely to emerge.)

Anyway, you can also take a look at this **[short demo](http://ideone.com/Zo6kYD)**.