# Analysing a more complex regex

Tags: java, regex

In a previous question that i asked,

[String split in java using advanced regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655796/string-split-in-java-using-advanced-regex)

someone gave me a fantastic answer to my problem (as described on the above link)
but i never managed to fully understand it. Can somebody help me? The regex i was given
is this"

```
"(?s)(?=(([^\"]+\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\\s+"
```

I can understand some basic things, but there are parts of this regex that even after 
thoroughly searching google i could not find, like the question mark preceding the s in the
start, or how exactly the second parenthesis works with the question mark and the equation in the start. Is it possible also to expand it and make it able to work with other types of quotes, like “ ” for example?

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Since it checks that there are even number of `"` ahead, if the quotes in the input is not paired up correctly, the result will be the first quote will not be effective, and pairing starts from the second quote.

Comment: possible duplicate of [String split in java using advanced regex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16655796/string-split-in-java-using-advanced-regex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`"(?s)(?=(([^\"]+\"){2})*[^\"]*$)\\s+"` Explained;

```
(?s)    # This equals a DOTALL flag in regex, which allows the `.` to match newline characters. As far as I can tell from your regex, it's superfluous.
(?=     # Start of a lookahead, it checks ahead in the regex, but matches "an empty string"(1) read more about that [here][1] 
(([^\"]+\"){2})*  # This group is repeated any amount of times, including none. I will explain the content in more detail.
    ([^\"]+\")    # This is looking for one or more occurrences of a character that is not `"`, followed by a `"`. 
    {2}           # Repeat 2 times. When combined with the previous group, it it looking for 2 occurrences of text followed by a quote. In effect, this means it is looking for an even amount of `"`.
[^\"]*  # Matches any character which is not a double quote sign. This means literally _any_ character, including newline characters without enabling the DOTALL flag
$       # The lookahead actually inspects until end of string.
)       # End of lookahead
\\s+    # Matches one or more  whitespace characters, including spaces, tabs and so on
```

That complicated group up there that is repeated twice will match in whitespaces in this string which is not in between two `"`;

```
text that has a "string in it".
```

When used with String.split, splitting the string into; `[text, that, has, a, "string in it".]`

It will only match if there are an even number of `"`, so the following will match on all spaces;

```
text that nearly has a "string in it.
```

Splitting the string into `[text, that, nearly, has, a, "string, in, it.]`

(1) When I say that a capture group matches "an empty string", I mean that it actually captures nothing, it only looks ahead from the point in the regex you are, and check a condition, nothing is actually captured. The actual capture is done by `\\s+` which follows the lookahead.

Answer (score 1):

The `(?s)` part is an *embedded flag expression*, enabling the [`DOTALL`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#DOTALL) mode, which means the following:

> *In dotall mode, the expression . matches any character, including a line terminator. By default this expression does not match line terminators.*

The `(?=expr)` is a *look-ahead* expression. This means that the regex looks to match `expr`, but then moves back to the same point before continuing with the rest of the evaluation.

In this case, it means that the regex matches any `\\s+` occurence, that is followed by any even number of `"`, then followed by non-`"` until the end (`$`). In other words, it checks that there are an even number of `"` ahead.

It can definitely be expanded to other quotes too. The only problem is the `([^\"]+\"){2}` part, that will probably have to be made to use a back-reference (`\n`) instead of the `{2}`.

Answer (score 1):

This is fairly simple..

**Concept**

It split's at `\s+` whenever there are **even** number of `"` ahead.

For example:

```
Hello hi "Hi World"
     ^  ^   ^
     |  |   |->will not split here since there are odd number of "
     ----
      |
      |->split here because there are even number of " ahead
```

---

**Grammar**

`\s` matches a `\n` or `\r` or `space` or `\t`

`+` is a quantifier which matches previous character or group 1 to many times

`[^\"]` would match anything except `"`

`(x){2}` would match `x` 2 times

`a(?=bc)` would match if a is followed by bc

`(?=ab)a` would first check for ab from current position and then return back to its position.It then matches a.`(?=ab)c` would not match c

With `(?s)`(singleline mode) `.` would match newlines.So,In this case no need of `(?s)` since there are no `.`

---

I would use

```
\s+(?=([^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)
```